Should you train participants during a formative evaluation?
When running a formative evaluation during the development process of a medical product (requires FDA clearance), should you provide any training to the participants before asking them to go through the eval?

This device is very specialized and only to be used by trained professionals.
The participants are currently using an older version of the device in their daily practice.
The changes that are being evaluated do not exist in any shape or form on the device currently BUT they do exist on other similar devices the participants may or may not have used.

Thank you!

Before providing any training you should ask some questions to quantify how much experience and insight your users have with this or similar devices and the context of their use. Any "training" you provide should be as contextual as possible, nothing to aid in use of your device.
I used to UXR for military tech, which was a large-scale upgrade of a comms system that probably skipped a few stages of growth other armies/units had gone through. While my users had seen and used similar devices, the scope of usage for this upgrade would be beyond their current understanding. So I drafted out complex contextual scenarios to run them through in the evaluation. It wasn't training per se, more equipping them with the knowledge needed to get through the evaluation and focus their feedback on the design.
